what are the steps to run Grub Hook Script in Debian 12.5
I have installed Software RAID 1 in Debian 12.5. I want if 1st HDD fails the automatically my system should be able to boot from 2nd HDD and visa versa.
What steps I should take for the same?
My Server has GPT disk partition. My 1st HDD has /boot/efi but not the 2nd HDD.
So from this article I have understood that I have to Format Grub Partition of 2nd HDD and mount the same on /boot/efi2.
I have created the Grub Hook Script "/etc/grub.d/90_copy_to_boot_efi2" as mentioned in the above article.
Do I need to have the same name of the script or any other name will do ?
what are the steps to be run after creating script ?
Do I need to install grub in both the HDD and then run update-grub ?
Please clarify on the steps to be performed.

You can take a look at :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/599813/run-a-script-after-every-grub-update
Which provide a detailed answer.
Check that rsync is installed and /etc/grub.d/90_copy_to_boot_efi2 is executable.
Then run grub-mkconfig.
If I understand correctly, /etc/grub.d/90_copy_to_boot_efi2 will be executed every time grub-mkconfig is executed.
